# Disabling Android "autocorrect" for specific field

Tags: android, xamarin-studio

I'm working on an Android app and at the front there's a login page. The Android keyboard often interrupts the users input and corrects their username to something else. It's possible for the user to just persevere and input their username but it can take a few tries. Is there a way to stop the keyboard from automatically correcting the user's input whilst entering text into that specific field?

Comment: Be warned we ran into some problems with certain Samsung S4s that seemed to ignore the flags we set on the EditTexts. Just a heads up on that...

Comment: I'll test it on an S4 before I deploy it but if it doesn't work on _some_ phones it's not a complete tragedy provided that it works on most. It's just an annoyance, really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
EditText etUsername = ............;

etUsername.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

To do this in xml, add this to your EditText:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: I was also thinking about this, but I think autocorrect is different from suggestions.

Comment: This, along with textVisiblePassword fixed the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @JamesMonger That's great. I've actually used `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` alone with the same results.

Comment: I thought it best to use both just in case a rare event occurs where a phone only supports one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

`android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"` works for me for this problem. This will take away any suggestion from the android keypad when typing.